# Handle MalformedURLException exception inside try catch block

Tags: java, exception

I have a piece of code that downloads a file from the given URL. I'm using an `InputStream` to read data from the stream.

```
public static byte[] fetchAttachmentFromThisURL(String path) {
    String urlString = ORBEON_BASE + path;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    URL obj = new URL(urlString);
    InputStream is = obj.openStream();
    int n;
    byte[] byteChunk = new byte[4096];
    while ((n = is.read(byteChunk)) > 0) {
        baos.write(byteChunk, 0, n);
    }
    is.close();
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

`URL obj = new URL(urlString);` throws `MalformedURLException` and `is.close();` throws an `IOException`.

My objective is to handle all the exceptions within the method `fetchAttachmentFromThisURL`. I don't want to use the `throws` keyword with the method.

**METHOD DESIGN 1:**

```
public static byte[] fetchAttachmentFromThisURL(String path) {
    String urlString = ORBEON_BASE + path;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        URL obj = new URL(urlString);
        is = obj.openStream();
        int n;
        byte[] byteChunk = new byte[4096];
        while ((n = is.read(byteChunk)) > 0) {
            baos.write(byteChunk, 0, n);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

In the `finally`, there must be another `try-catch` block to handle the `IOException`, which is definitely not a cleaner approach.

**METHOD DESIGN 2:**

```
public static byte[] fetchAttachmentFromThisURL(String path) {
    String urlString = ORBEON_BASE + path;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    URL obj = new URL(urlString);
    try (InputStream is = obj.openStream()) {
        int n;
        byte[] byteChunk = new byte[4096];
        while ((n = is.read(byteChunk)) > 0) {
            baos.write(byteChunk, 0, n);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();            
    }
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

Here, there's a compile time error as the `obj` initialization throws a `MalformedURLException`. Again, I cannot move this initialization line inside try block, as doing so would make the `obj` invisible.

The input stream has to be closed in the `finally` block unless using `try-catch` with `resource`.

Is there any way to achieve the mentioned objective (if possible only by using one `try-catch` block) ?

Comment: you know that you can catch multiple exceptions in 1 catch block right?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer, can you answer with the method design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This design was suggested by Eclipse IDE. I assume that there shouldn't be any resource leaks as well as exceptions.

```
public static byte[] fetchAttachmentFromThisURL(String path) {
    String urlString = "" + path;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        URL obj = new URL(urlString);
        int n;
        byte[] byteChunk = new byte[4096];
        while ((n = obj.openStream().read(byteChunk)) > 0) {
            baos.write(byteChunk, 0, n);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: That's a clever way to hide the `InputStream`. But I wonder, should the anonymous `InputStream` object be closed?

Comment: @mark42inbound I am not quite sure, but I think that we are not having any resource leak here (at least Eclipse isn't showing one, which it does if you use other ways)

Comment: In NetBeans it gives this error: **Alternatives in a multi-catch statement cannot be related by subclassing
  Alternative MalformedURLException is a subclass of alternative IOException** . Turns out `MalformedURLException` is a subclass of `IOException`. Simply removing the `MalformedURLException` and keeping the `IOException` solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Method 1 but without the `finally` to close the stream but instead of a `try-with-resources` statement.
Note that the in your code, `is.close();` statement will throw `NullPointerException` if `is` is `null` in the case of `IOException` thrown by `URL`.
By leaving the stream closing task to the JVM, you avoid adding a check for and additionally a `finally`:

```
public static byte[] fetchAttachmentFromThisURL(String path) {
    String urlString = ORBEON_BASE + path;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try (InputStream is = new URL(urlString).openStream()) {                       
        int n;
        byte[] byteChunk = new byte[4096];
        while ((n = is.read(byteChunk)) > 0) {
            baos.write(byteChunk, 0, n);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: shouldn't the opened `InputStream` resource be closed?

Comment: you are not catching the `MalformedURLException`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer `MalformedURLException` is a `IOException`. It is so caught in the `catch (IOException e)` statement.

Comment: my bad then. assuming you want to differentiate between those 2 types. is it possible if you don't include the `MalformedURLException`?

Comment: This is assuming Java 7+ just as a heads up. Probably a non-issue in most cases.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Yes with an additional `catch` statement  : `catch (MalformedURLException  e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }` But I am not sure to get your point.